# dns client restart greyed out

Tags: windows, dns, services

Pretty basic question:

I enter `services.msc` on Windows 10.

I navigate to **DNS client**

I right-click to restart **DNS client**

All options are greyed out (start, stop, restart).

How do I fix this?

Note: I tried opening services by right-clicking and choosing "Run as Administrator" - did not fix the issue.

Comment: Check the dependecies services if they are running or not

Comment: Seems related: https://superuser.com/q/1277952

Answer (score 2):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/grayed-out-services-in-windows-10/346bd141-13e2-42de-b93a-c4481b23ec43?page=2

I found the I was able to use regedit to disable dnscache.

I will say that it is ridiculous to lose the ability to change this from the services control panel. I also tried disabling it using msconfig and even unchecking the box didn't disable it.

Here are the directions the finally worked.

win+x run regedit

Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Dnscache and
locate Start registry key

Change Startup type :

Automatic -2
Manual -3
Disabled -4
Automatic (Delayed Start) -2

Answer (score 1):

Restart Dnscache in new Windows 10 (where Dnscache placed in isolated process) via PowerShell:

```
$ServicePID = (get-wmiobject win32_service | where { $_.name -eq 'Dnscache'}).processID
Stop-Process $ServicePID -Force
```

Place code:

```
PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -NoLogo -Command "try { $ServicePID = (get-wmiobject win32_service | where { $_.name -eq 'Dnscache'}).processID; Stop-Process $ServicePID -Force } catch {}"
```

into bat-file and this able to automatization.

Comment: This should become the right answer, thanks!